# unable to start program--access denied when try to run VTK examples

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am trying to run the ***"VTK examples"*** by visual studio 2013 on Windows 10 Professional 64-bit.

I have made the ***"VTK examples***" by CMake and I read the source code from (C:\vtk\src) file. Then I built the binary in the (C:\vtk\bin.qt5.64bit) file.

The ***"VTKExamples.sln"*** has been built in (C:\vtk\bin.qt5.64bit). However, when I open ***"VTKExamples.sln"*** in the Visual Studio(2013), and click on "Start Debugging", the ***unable to start program--access denied*** error pops up.

I have no idea how to deal with this error. Please help me to get rid of the error and be able to run the ***"VTKExamples.sln"*** in VS.

I appreciate any help. Thank you for your time and consideration.

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to build software in a protected folder which requires you to run Visual Studio as an Administrator?

Comment: Actually I have installed the VTK step by step based on its instruction, and I did not choose to make a protected folder. Can you guide me more?

Comment: The root directory of the system drive is always protected.  Your tutorial is dated.  As long as you are running everything as an Administrator it shouldn't matter.  It's just inefficient.  When you say you are opening "it", what exactly is "it", your question is unclear in this regard.

Comment: First, thanks for your consideration. Second, I am not running the .sln file in VS 2013 as an administrator, but I tried running as admin. However, I still get this error.

Comment: I tried running as admin and still got same problem, tried setting full control for all users, still same problem

Comment: I'm wondering if the file attributes have read only set, not sure if that will help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988429/unable-to-start-program-vs2015-access-denied-system-cannot-find-the-file-spe